# Prove $xe^x =2$ for some $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> We are trying to prove $xe^x =2$ for some $x \in (0,1)$.

I know for certain that if this question were asking to prove the equality for some $x$ in the closed interval $[0,1]$ then I could apply the intermediate value theorem:

- Let $f(x) = xe^x$ implying:

$f(0) = 0 \lt 2$ and $f(1) = 1\cdot e^1=e \gt 2$ and by the intermediate value theorem there must exist some $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=2$.

- My question is if we can use the Intermediate Value Theorem in my original question - where we have $x \in (0,1)$ the open interval.

I know the discrepancy arises since the interval is open and there is no explicit definition of the function at the end-points $0$ and $1$.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Yes, we can. The IVT arises from the fact that a continuous function sends connected sets to connected sets, and that a connected set in $\Bbb R$ is an interval (of any kind, open, semi-open or closed).

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $f(x)=2$ some point in the interval $[0,1]$, and we know for a fact that it's not $0$ or $1$, we know that $f(x)=2$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: This makes sense intuitively but how can we prove this rigorously? Is the intermediate value theorem used at all in this proof?

Comment: My proof WAS proving it rigorously. You use the intermediate value theorem to get that $f(x)=2$ on $[0,1]$. We know that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are not $2$, so $f(x)=2$ in the interval $(0,1)$. There's nothing left to prove.

Comment: Ah, thank you, got it.

Comment: @avid19 However, notice you're using the fact that the function is defined on $0$ and $1$, such an argument cannot be applied to a function as for example $\frac{1}{x}$ defined on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @DavidSouth I don't think he means in this particular case. The given $f$ in the problem is defined on $[0,1]$. He just means you can't generalize it, as is the case of $\frac1x$.

Comment: @DavidSouth Avid is right (be careful, $1/x$ is defined in $1$). One can overpass this, for example, considering intervals of the form $[\epsilon,1)$ for sufficient small $\epsilon>0$, however, don't overthink this, It was just an unnecesary comment for the actual problem.

Comment: @SolidSnake Thank you guys! However, I am curious about the case where we have this "awkward" situation - where we have to use the intermediate value theorem to prove $\frac 1 x$ takes on some $x \in (0,1)$. How could we apply IVT in this situation where $ \frac 1 x $ is not defined at $0$

Comment: For that case, you can explicitly compute it! For example, lets say you wanted to show that $\frac{1}{x}=7$ on $(0,1)$. Just let $x=\frac17$ :). But what if it was some crazy function defined on an open interval, basically you would do what @SolidSnake said, consider some closed interval that's cleverly chosen.

Comment: @DavidSouth I've added an answer to show the kind of things we can try on those cases (however, in this case -as Avid noted- it's easier to compute the preimage directly).

Comment: @avid19 thank you guys so much haha

Answer (score 5):

I post this answer in order to clarify a discusion that arose on Avid's answer.

> Suppose we have the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ defined on $(0,1)$ and
>   we want to prove that $f(z)=2$ for some $z\in (0,1]$ using the Intermediate 
>   Value Theorem (of course, it would be easier to say $z=\frac{1}{2}$,
>   but that's not the idea here).
>
> Well, we argue as follows:
>
> Consider the function restricted to $[\frac{1}{4},1]$, since
>   $f(1)=1<2<4=f(1/4)$, by IVT there is some $z\in [\frac{1}{4},1]\subseteq (0,1]$ such
>   that $f(z)=2$.
>
> (Note all of this argument requires continuity of $f$).

Answer (score 1):

We can show this directly by using [The Lambert W](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) function, which is defined as $f(W)=We^{W}$.

Thus, $xe^x=2 \implies x=W(2)\approx. 0.85260550201372549134647241$.

Thus, we have $xe^x=2$ for $0<x\approx. 0.85260550201372549134647241<1$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=e>2$ then the function must have a root between $0$ and $1$.